# How to check Mac's uptime since last reset?

Tags: mac, macbook, macbook-pro

I  want to know How months my Mac is operating from the last reset time .

Comment: Hey, refer this article it will help you. https://www.idownloadblog.com/2019/01/10/mac-reboot-shutdown-hiistory-howto/#:~:text=1)%20Click%20on%20the%20Apple,boot%E2%80%9D%20in%20the%20righthand%20section.

Comment: Did you even do a web search before posting this?  You literally had the command right in your question: `uptime`

Comment: I don't want any one of those, I just need time from the last reset

Comment: Then you're going to have to explain precisely what you mean by the term 'reset'. It's not one I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 2):

In Terminal, you can get

- Time since last boot with `uptime`
- History of reboots with `last reboot`
- History of shutdowns with `last shutdown`

Comment: I don't want any one of those, I just need time from the last reset

Comment: You're going to have to tell us what you mean by 'reset', it's not a term used for Macs.